# Jquery - Using keyup() to set header element text

Tags: jquery

Looking to understand why this doesn't work:

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" id="pageInput">
<p id="pageTitle">Test Title</p>
```

**JQuery**:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#pageInput').keyup(function(){
    $('#pageTitle').text($(this).val())
  })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/czm7p06o/

Comment: What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The fiddle does not seem to have jQuery added as resource. After adding it, the code works (in the sense that `keyup` is fired and `<p>` element value changes to whatever value the input box holds.

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/czm7p06o/2/ , it works only that jquery wasn't included in your fiddle.

Comment: Oops! Okay thank you. I'm still learning JQuery and just wanted to make sure I wasn't crazy. I'll go back and figure out why it doesn't work in my own project.